# Getting image URL embedded in <script> tag with Python requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to use [Python requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to get the url of an image in [this web](https://smn.conagua.gob.mx/tools/GUI/visor_radares_v2/radares/cabos/cabos_ppi.php?). Especifically, I'd like to get the URL to the image that starts with `PPI_Z_005...`

Now, to get this, I try to get the html with Python requests.

```py
weburl="https://smn.conagua.gob.mx/tools/GUI/visor_radares_v2/radares/cabos/cabos_ppi.php"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36'
           '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(weburl, verify=False, headers=headers)
```

The problem is that the response has no explicit reference to the file name I'm looking for. I guess the problem is that it is somehow rendered by JavaScript, and inserted within a `<script>` tag. Indeed, when I inspect the source code of the web with the browser's developers tool, it contains this:

```
  <script>
    [...]
    imagen_eco(/* Radar */ 'cabos', /* Nombre imagen */ "PPI_Z_005_300_20220206141529.png", /* Producto */ 'ppi', /* Limites */ [[25.589004,-112.910417],[20.147021,-106.944245]]);
    [...]
  </script>
```

I guess this tag is somehow responsible to insert the image in the rendered webpage... but how?

Is it possible to use **requests alone** to parse this web and obtain this filename?

NOTE: I'm aware that this can be accomplished using *selenium*. I'm specifically looking for a selenium-free solution.

Comment: I'd like to know too, so I've bookmarked your question. I suspect, though, that there is no image to `GET` from the server, the image is rendered in the browser, and therefore to get the image you need either a browser or something that acts like one.

Comment: I don't think so. Once you know the URL (for example using your browser), you can use `requests.get` to download the image normally. I just need an URL.

Comment: The PNG URL alone would be fine.

Comment: Is the PPI image just the weather overlay, or does it have OpenStreetMap rendered into it also?

Comment: It's a radar overlay. You can see the image, and get its URL, in the "Network" tab of the developer tool in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution with requests and regex to find the data that you are looking for.

```
import requests
import re


weburl = (
    "https://smn.conagua.gob.mx/tools/GUI/visor_radares_v2/radares/cabos/cabos_ppi.php"
)
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36"
    "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(weburl, verify=False, headers=headers)

source = response.content.decode("utf-8")

imagen_eco = re.search("imagen_eco((.*?));", source)
if not imagen_eco:
    exit("Not found")

image_name = re.search(r"([\w-]+)\.png", imagen_eco.group(0))
if not image_name:
    exit("Not found")
print(image_name.group(0))
print(
    f"https://smn.conagua.gob.mx/tools/GUI/visor_radares_v2/ecos/cabos/ppi/{image_name.group(0)}"
)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. I was not aware of the obvious: the response contains the script "as is", so you can work on it with regex.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it helped!